# jquery addclass to the current a tag, not to all a tags inside div

Tags: jquery

I want to add an "active" class to the current link, I have the following code:

The jquery:

```
$("#products a").each(function() {
if(this.href == window.location || this.href == document.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname)
$(this).addClass("selectedThumb");
```

});

The html:

```
<div id="products">
  <a>First product</a>
  <a>Second product</a>
</div>
```

I want to end up with just current link that is clicked having the "selectedThumb" class added. Right now the class is being added to all the a tags and I'm ending up with this:

```
<div id="products">
  <a class="selectedThumb">First product</a>
  <a class="selectedThumb">Second product</a>
</div>
```

This is a product image thumb viewer, so I'm always staying on the current page, not leaving the page after the a link is clicked, instead the product thumbnail changes on the page.  That code works fine.  Not sure if this could have smth to do with it.

ADDITIONAL INFO

The a tags that I'm trying to add the 'active' state / css class to are thumb images that when hovered have a mouseover event that display that thumb in that page, and the thumbs have no link.

The mouseover event calls a JS function that displays the correct product image.

The JS it calls:

```
function displayImage(index, parent){
var images = document.getElementById(parent).getElementsByTagName("div");

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var image = images[i];
  if (image.className != 'pimage')  { continue }
  if(i == index-1) {
    image.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    image.style.display="none";
  }     
}
```

}

So because the a links don't really link anywhere, the jQuery addClass is being added to all the thumbnail links.

Comment: `<a>` tags should always have a `href` attribute (unless you're using them as a named anchor, which isn't the case here). The browser will not render them as links (and won't apply the hover events, etc) without a `href`. The common approach is to set `href="#"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to be more clear in your code about what you're trying to do. If you're trying to only apply a class to a certain link, then only select that link:

```
$('#products a[href="' + window.location.href + '")
    .addClass('selectedThumb')
;
```

If this was something you particularly needed to select often, it might be neat to extend jQuery:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    currentPage: function(el) {
        return el.href && el.href === window.location.href;
    }
});

// then...
$('a:currentPage').addClass('selectedThumb');
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick responses!  I added some more details on my code, hope that helps a bit.  @nick, I tried your example but for some reason not working still.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to match the url (untested):

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$("#products a").each(function() {
 if (loc.match(this.href) { $(this).addClass("selectedThumb"); }
});
```

Comment: `loc.match(this.href)` isn't a good comparator. `"http://example.com/some/deep/link".match("http://example.com") == true`

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming he was using relative paths =/